# Why are F# list ranges so much slower than for loops?

Tags: list, f#

I'm surprised how much slower the List range is for the example below.  On my machine the for loop is a factor of 8 or so quicker.

Is an actual list of 10,000,000 elements created first?  And if so, is there a reason (other than it has not been done yet) why this can't be optimised away by the compiler?

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics

let timeFunction f v =
    let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    let result = f v
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

let length = 10000000

let doSomething n =
    (float n) ** 0.1 |> ignore

let listIter n =
    [1..length] |> List.iter (fun x -> doSomething (x+n))

let forLoop n = 
    for x = 1 to length do
        doSomething (x+n)

printf "listIter   : %d\n" (timeFunction listIter 1)  // c50
GC.Collect()
printf "forLoop    : %d\n" (timeFunction forLoop 1)  // c1000
GC.Collect()
```

Comment: You're creating a list. An actual list. During runtime. That involves many allocations. The loop doesn't allocate anything. You might have better luck with `{0..length} |> Seq.iter` because that doesn't allocate anything. It will still be slower, but not by much.

Comment: `seq` is much faster, but still 2.5x slower than `forLoop`. I added timings to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using ILSpy, `listIter` looks like this:

```
public static void listIter(int n)
{
    ListModule.Iterate<int>(
        new listIter@17(n), 
        SeqModule.ToList<int>(
            Operators.CreateSequence<int>(
                Operators.OperatorIntrinsics.RangeInt32(1, 1, 10000000)
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Here are the basic steps involved:

1. `RangeInt32` creates an `IEnumerable` (which is inexplicably wrapped by `CreateSequence`)
2. `SeqModule.ToList` builds a list from that sequence
3. An instance of `listIter@17` (your lambda) is new'd up
4. `ListModule.Iterate` traverses the list calling the lambda for each element

vs `forLoop`, which doesn't look much different from what you've written:

```
public static void forLoop(int n)
{
    for (int x = 1; x < 10000001; x++)
    {
        int num = x + n;
        double num2 = Math.Pow((double)num, 0.1);
    }
}
```

...no `IEnumerable`, lambda (it's automatically inlined), or list creation. There's a potentially significant difference in the amount of work being done.

EDIT

For curiosity's sake, here are FSI timings for `list`, `seq`, and `for` loop versions:

```
listIter - Real: 00:00:03.889, CPU: 00:00:04.680, GC gen0: 57, gen1: 51, gen2: 6  
seqIter  - Real: 00:00:01.340, CPU: 00:00:01.341, GC gen0:  0, gen1:  0, gen2: 0  
forLoop  - Real: 00:00:00.565, CPU: 00:00:00.561, GC gen0:  0, gen1:  0, gen2: 0
```

and the `seq` version for reference:

```
let seqIter n =
    {1..length} |> Seq.iter (fun x -> doSomething (x+n))
```

Comment: Another part of the reason is that with the for loop, the generated code is simple, fast, and has good data locality. The code for the range has a lot of jumps/branches which add a lot of latency to each individual step of the loop.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the creation of the list is the problem. Creating a list involves many non-local heap allocations. The jump/branch thing is probably a very small problem in comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Using `{1..length} |> Seq.iter`
is certainly faster as you don't create the full list in memory.

Another slightly faster way than your for loop is:

```
let reclist n =
    let rec downrec x n =
        match x with 
        | 0 -> ()
        | x -> doSomething (x+n); downrec (x-1) n
    downrec length n
```

Interesting is that the code for the recursive function boils down to:

```
while (true)
{
    switch (x)
    {
    case 0:
        return;
    default:
    {
        int num = x + n;
        double num2 = Math.Pow((double)num, 0.1);
        int arg_26_0 = x - 1;
        n = n;
        x = arg_26_0;
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Even when using optimization, there are still a few lines that could have been removed, i.e to this:

```
while (true)
{
    switch (x)
    {
    case 0:
        return;
    default:
    {
        int num = x + n;
        double num2 = Math.Pow((double)num, 0.1);
        x = x - 1;
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how `forinlist` can be faster than `forLoop`; it compiles to exactly the same thing.

Comment: I get slightly different timings, but maybe only due to the JIT. The code as you say are identical in the "for..in" case. I do however get roughly the same results every time I run these functions. The order may have some impact on the results.
listIter   : 4457
forLoop    : 586
arrayiter    : 1893
seqIter    : 1803
forinlist    : 567
reclist: 569